# For every open cover of an infinite compact set, we cannot bound the number of terms in its subcover

Tags: real-analysis

This is for $\mathbb R^1$.

I'm trying to prove this space by contradiction, saying that to the contrary, we assume that for every open cover of a set $S$, the finite subcover is at max $N$. I want to try and break this by breaking up an open interval into two, so we have a subcover of size $N+1$. Is this the right way to go about this? The problem is that there are some intervals that when you split, you don't get more intervals. For example, let's say we have $[0,5]$ and I'm examining the open interval around 2. Let's say we have $(1,2) \cup (1.5, 2.5) \cup (2,3)$. Then, splitting the middle interval is useless because we don't get an extra interval.
Been stuck for a day on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you need to change up your approach??

Comment: @amWhy what're your suggestions? I'm asking here because I've been stumped

Comment: @erfgerwge the definition of compact space says that every open cover has a finite subcover. what does your title mean instead?

Comment: @l4teLearner I've been trying to prove that if you have an open cover for a compact set, its finite subcover cannot be bounded in terms of its cardinality: that is, if we have an open cover with a finite subcover of size $N$, there will always exist another open cover whose finite subcover is larger than $N$.

Comment: what if instead of going by contradiction you try to prove that for any N sufficiently large you can always find a cover of N elements with no subcover? in $\mathbb{R}$ it should be possible I believe.

Comment: I don't find the question precise enough. Is there a specific set you're looking at open covers of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the approach where you can make the size of the finite subcover as large as you like. The most straightforward way to do this, considering the example of the compact set $[0,1]$, would be to consider the union $(0-\epsilon, \frac{1}{n})\cup(\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon, \frac{2}{n})\cup... \cup(\frac{n-1}{n}-\epsilon,1)\cup(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon).$

For any $n$, this is an open cover of $[0,1]$. And for any $n$, if you make $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that no set is contained in another, this is also the only finite subcover. Said subcover has size $n+1$. Hence, you can make the subcover arbitrarily large.